# Capistrano: deploy files other than used in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I have a rails application that uses some bash scripts that have different values (paths) in them for development and production. I want to use capistrano to deploy the app using the values suitable for production.
So for example in #{Rails.root}+'script.sh':

```
 #!/bin/bash
 /usr/local/bin/convert  -colorspace sRGB -background transparent -font Myriad-Pro-Condensed -fill grey0 -stroke yellow -strokewidth 2 -size 640x480 -gravity $3 label:"$2" $1.png
```

For production I will need:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 /usr/bin/convert  -colorspace sRGB -background transparent -font Myriad-Pro-Condensed -fill grey0 -stroke yellow -strokewidth 2 -size 640x480 -gravity $3 label:"$2" $1.png
```

Is there a solution which involves changing files on the fly, while deploying (with some gsub command, that changes values)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An ERB template is probably the most straightforward. Inside the template you can access all the Capistrano variables so you can tell what stage you are in, etc. The cap code would look something like this:

```
template = File.read(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "templates/script.sh.erb"))
result = ERB.new(template).result(binding)
put result, "#{release_path}/script.sh"
```

Comment: thanks! Any chance you can point to some place that explains how to use templates with Capistrano? Could not find anything apart from paid Railscast

Comment: here is an example: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/06/capistrano-and-database-yml/.  He doesn't exercise it in that simple example but you have access to all the capistrano object model, variables, etc. inside the erb template.